# Close a figure - PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I have spent over an hour searching, just to figure this simple thing. So, before considering this a duplicate question, please compare my question to any question out there.

This is my code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pandas.read_csv('international-airline-passengers.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python', skipfooter=1)
print dataset, type(dataset)
plt.plot(dataset)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Firstly, `plt.show()` to my understanding is a blocking function. So what is the way to close the figure. There is no point in writing `plt.close()` after it. So where is the right way to put it.

Secondly, how can I make sure all the windows are closed when I execute a new process of the same python code. For example in MATLAB, one could easily say close all in the beginning of their file and it closes all the opened plots which were the result of previous MATLAB code execution. `plt.close('all')` is not working either.

I am using PyCharm. The results I found for the first situation, might work on IDLE but not in the PyCharm. How can I do it PyCharm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843250/how-could-i-close-a-plot-in-python-and-then-reopen-it#comment92605808_52844016

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`plt.show(block=False)` will do the trick- This is the way you can make this function non-blocking (both in run & debug mode). The main dis-advantage is that if the code ends, the figure is automatically closes...

Comment: You can put a final `plt.show()` at the very end, so that the figure windows are kept open without ending the program, until you close all by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
I fix it making the python file in Pycharm to run in only one console. Go to: run---Edit configuration-- check that "single instance only" is activated

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to run matplotlib, non-interactive and interactive.  In non-interactive mode, the default, you are right that `plt.show()` is blocking.  In this case, calling `plt.close()` is pointless, the code won't stop as long as the figure is open.  In interactive mode, however (which can be triggers by `plt.ion()`), this code will open then immediately close the figure.  You would need to put something to wait for user input if you run code like this in a script.  Interactive mode, as the name implies, is designed more for running interactively rather than in a script.

As for closing figures from multiple runs of a python script, this isn't possible.  If you open multiple instances of MATLAB, `close all` in one instance won't close the figures in another instance.  Running multiple processes of the same python code is the same as opening multiple instances of MATLAB, one run has no knowledge of the others.

Comment: May be I wrongly used the word process. In MATLAB, if you have a close all line on top of the code. Run the code - which opens a figure. Run the code again, the figure which was opened gets closed. Is there no way I can do that in Python? I am not opening multiple instances of MATLAB here. Same instance running the same code twice.

Comment: @JeshKundem Right, but if you run a python script multiple times, you are opening multiple instances of python.  So my  point is that running a python script multiple times is equivalent to running a MATLAB script in separate MATLAB instances.  If you want to run the same code multiple times in the same instance of python, you should be using a function, not a script, and you should run it from a python shell.  Or better yet use something like the ipython/jupyter notebook to keep all of your code and figures organized.