# How could I close a plot in python and then reopen it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, charts

**So I have this code:**

```
plt.style.use('bmh')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(months, monthly_profit, 'b-',lw=3)
plt.xlabel('Monthhs')
plt.ylabel('Profit')
plt.yticks(np.arange(10000,25000,step=1500))
plt.title('Profit Chart')
play = True
while play:
  x = int(input("State your choise : "))
  if x == 3:
    plt.show()
  print("Would you like to continue? YES or NO?")
  y = input()
  if y == "NO":
    play = False
  plt.close("all")
```

And it seems like it doesn't close the plot at all. Not with close('all') ,nor with close(). What I'd like is to be able to open it and keep it open until the user states his answer, and afterwards ,close it.
Any help? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your plot does not close is because `plt.show()` blocks execution, so your code doesn't even reach the `plt.close("all")` line. To fix this you can use `plt.show(block=False)` to continue execution after calling `show`.

To reopen plots and have your loop work as I believe you are expecting it to, you need to move the plot creation logic to within the `while` loop. Note, however, that `plt.style.use('bmh')` must not be placed in this loop.

Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# sample data
months = [1,2,3]
monthly_profit = [10, 20, 30]

plt.style.use('bmh')

play = True
while play:
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  ax.plot(months, monthly_profit, 'b-',lw=3)
  plt.xlabel('Monthhs')
  plt.ylabel('Profit')
  plt.yticks(np.arange(10000,25000,step=1500))
  plt.title('Profit Chart')

  x = int(input("State your choise : "))
  if x == 3:
    plt.show(block=False)
  print("Would you like to continue? YES or NO?")
  y = input()
  if y == "NO":
    play = False
  plt.close("all")
```

Comment: I just tried the code.
It seems that now I can create multiple plots if i choose "3" , but still , it doesn't close them.

Comment: @manubmxnsb do you get the prompt `"Would you like to continue? YES or NO?"` in your console?

Comment: Yes, I do. And It stops only if i choose "NO"

Comment: @manubmxnsb isn't that the expected behavior? Also are you sure you have everything as I have put it here? because on my computer the plot closes regardless of the YES/NO choice

Comment: Its weird bc it doesn't close at all. I tried modifying my code into this one,and it didn't work. 
I copy pasted this code into python and tried it and still, it doesn't close it

Comment: Might be bc i'm using pycharm?

Comment: Indeed it was! The fact that i'm using pycharm was the problem -_- 
When i ran the code in cmd ,it closed all the plots. Thank you very much! ^_^

Comment: @manubmxnsb yeah I was just looking into that. I found this question, which might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413986/close-a-figure-pycharm

Comment: @manubmxnsb yeah it's responsive for me in the Python interpreter directly. However depending on the interpreter you might need to remove all blank lines from within the `while` loop—the default interpreter will end the `while` block upon encountering a blank line—resulting in an infinite loop of the `plt` setup logic. However if you put this code in a `.py` file then run the file (`python file.py`) in the terminal it'll work fine