# Closing a matplotlib figure in Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I'd like to plot a figure using matplotlib using PyCharm, show the figure for a few seconds, and then close the plot window.

After a simple search I've got the following code. This works when Python is run in IDLE/terminal.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.imshow(np.zeros((256,256)))
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(10)
plt.close('all')
```

However plt.close('all') doesn't seem to close any plot windows produced by PyCharm.

How can I close plot windows produced by PyCharm programmatically? The question had been asked ([Close a figure - PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413986/close-a-figure-pycharm) ), but the accepted solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you use the SciView. So you need to change the setting in the pycharm.

```
Settings | Tools | Python Scientific | Show Plots in Toolwindow - box has to be unticked to back to the usual matplotlib figure window
```

After this, try again.