# Python process is not terminated after closing the plot window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib.pyplot to draw some graphs.
Once one is done and closes the plot window, the python process is not terminated.

A short example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.show()
```

How do I make sure that no python process is left spinning around after the Plot Window is closed?

Edit: from users replies, I understand the reason the Python process keep spinning around once I close the Plot window:
Using Shift+F10 in PyCharm execute the code, in console context. Meaning, that even if I close the Plot window, the PyCharm console is still active.
Remember to press the "Red Button" to kill the PyCharm Console as well, in order to kill any Python leftovers that still spin around.
thanks

Comment: How are you running this? If I make a plot from the Python prompt, I get the prompt back when I close the plot window. Same if I run a script. Whatever you're doing, my second question is: does `plt.close()` help?

Comment: My IDE is pyCharm, on windows, and I run the above simple program from the IDE itself.
As, to use plt.close() - it behaves similarly to sys.close(0), meaning - the plot closes immediately, but the python process is still running in the task manager.

Comment: Okay... I've never used PyCharm, but this looks like it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53681400/3381305

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close a figure - PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413986/close-a-figure-pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

You could exit the running process using sys:

```py
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.show()
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: It didn't work. I tried it though but this closes immediately all the plots